# Unable to find shader lib. Error in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am facing below error when I try to run gazebo any help regarding this is highly appreciated

```
  Error [RTShaderSystem.cc:408] Unable to find shader lib. Shader generating will fail.terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::ItemIdentityException'   what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(5:ItemIdentityException): Cannot locate material called 'Gazebo/shadow_caster' in SceneManager::setShadowTextureCasterMaterial at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreSceneManager.cpp (line 5833)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173633/unable-to-find-shader-lib.-error-in-gazebo/) by [Raghu Parvatha](https://answers.ros.org/users/15256/raghu-parvatha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haz88](https://answers.ros.org/users/22113/haz88/) on 2015-04-20**:
BH
I too ran into this error.
Are you using indigo with ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, this question is better suited to ask in [Gazebo answers](http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/), rather than ROS answers. In [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5516/error-rtshadersystemcc408-unable-to-find-shader-lib/) link you have your same question with many answers from the gazebo community.

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2018-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0